# How to convert HTML / Php code to pdf code

Tags: invoice, custom, pdf, magento-1.9

I had made a custom module for replacing the existing invoice pdf with my custom pdf, I displayed all the information using coordinates... Is there a way that I design all my pdf using normal html code with html tables and after that I can convert all that code to pdf code means assign coordinates automatically..

Comment: Try tcpdf, and override invoice pdf to use your tcpdf function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a custom module that renders the output as html instead of generating a PDF, then use a html2pdf utility to convert the output of that page into a PDF.

However, using this approach it is very likely that the generated PDF would not correctly use page break points.